# How many lines of code should developer write per day

Tags: programming-languages

On average, how many lines of code should a developer write per day?

I want to know how to answer this question.

Comment: Work smarter, not harder.

Comment: The historical answer is "about ten lines of code per day": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966800/mythical-man-month-10-lines-per-developer-day-how-close-on-large-projects

I've even heard that those ten lines of code are roughly constant no matter _which_ programming language you're using -- good high-level ones vs extremely low-level ones, functional or procedural, object oriented or not.

Comment: Also see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/103807/what-is-negative-code

Answer (score 5):

LoC is not an accurate way to describe productivity. It doesn't take into account how much work has been done, just how much your codebase has bloated. http://www.folklore.org/StoryView.py?project=Macintosh&story=Negative_2000_Lines_Of_Code.txt

Answer (score 2):

Some days you'll net none, other days you may net a few hundred. Depends heavily on the project, and the people involved.

Comment: Since I use the headfirst strategy in web development, its usually a day of writing tons of code, and a day of debugging with little lines of code

Answer (score 1):

As many as he or she should.

Comment: Measuring programming progress by lines of code is like measuring aircraft building progress by weight. -- Bill Gates

Answer (score -1):

That depends on so many factors it's impossible to give a general answer. Plus, how do you define "should"? Lines of code are also a poor measure of progress anyways...