# What is the programming language to create operating system or tools?

Tags: operating-system

I am wondering about operating systems on where they are made. Just like windows, what is the programming language that Mr. Bill Gates used to achieved that OS. Any answers are welcome.

Comment: You could, you know .. search. Anyway, C (with assembly as appropriate) is quite common in mainstay kernels and system-level tools/libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ..operating systems..where they are made?

In the minds of outstanding fearless guys with their hands during endless sleepless nights and days while influenced by shining inspiration

> ..Windows, what is the programming language that Mr.Bill Gates used..?

[History of Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/history#T1=era0) is long story. Some `assembly` language, some `C`, some `C++`, some shell scripting languages, combined together it is joint effort resulting in [several millions of lines of code](http://www.quora.com/How-many-lines-of-code-is-in-Microsoft-Windows-8).

Taking into account that average developer can produce [only a few lines of code per day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966800/mythical-man-month-10-lines-per-developer-day-how-close-on-large-projects), success of this project can not be easily repeated using scenario where one smart guy picks the right programming language and one day the sun shines and that guy becomes rich and happy and the world stands still with mouth wide open (I guess that was the original idea behind your question)

> ..what is the programming language that Mr. Bill Gates used to achieved that OS?

According to [Wikipedia: DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS) the OS sold by Mr.Bill Gates was actually developed by Mr.[Tim Paterson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Paterson) and the [historical articles available at his site](http://www.patersontech.com/dos/microsoft-micronews.aspx) indicate that it was written in `assembly` language

---

Even today, there are some cool guys able to create complete OS with GUI and networking etc. in **assembly language**, like those behind the [MenuetOS.net](http://www.menuetos.net/screens.htm) project.

And then there are another cool guys able to create complete OS in `C`, like Mr.Linus Torvalds and his https://github.com/torvalds/linux

And then there are guys able to create complete computer as an environment supporting imagination built from [visions and dreams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk) with OS and applications and development environment and everything, like those behind the [Squeak](http://www.squeak.org/) project which is based on the `smalltalk` language

...to be continued by ?...

---

<sub>Although your question seems like too broad without any research effort shown, I find it actually very good question. Every programmer needs to answer this question to (him/her)self one day, somehow. Hope that helps</sub>

Comment: Let's not get carried away here, Linus didn't create a complete OS :) (The feat is super-impressive nonetheless of course)

Comment: @keyser would you consider rewording `OS` into `OS kernel` closer to the reality?

Comment: Yes, that seems better, but you don't have to change anything really, I just wanted to mention it.

Comment: @keyser ok, I'll leave it as-is. According to the [GitHub commit charts](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/graphs/contributors) it seems that since Linus did the big kick-off his contribution stats to the kernel `360 commits / 12,857 ++ / 13,814 --` are less impressive than those of e.g. H Hartley Sweeten (bigguiness) `3,233 commits / 61,855 ++ / 108,553 --`. Anyway, I think that "_get carried away_" is quite useful (from time to time)

Comment: His wikipedia mentions that the kernel had about 2% of his code as of 2006, which still makes him one of the largest contributors though. Not that we should ever question the size of his overall contribution :)

Comment: @keyser the list of people who's contribution to the programming universe should be never questioned or forgotten is remarkably long, yet incomplete - [Quora: Who is considered to be the best programmer of all time?](http://www.quora.com/Who-is-considered-to-be-the-best-programmer-of-all-time)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to really good answers, I want to share an interesting project about the topic. A project called COSMOS let you create your very own operating system by using C# language. Of course, there was no C# and COSMOS at the time when Bill Gates and his friends create their OS.

Check the link below.

https://cosmos.codeplex.com/

An Instructable is written for this. You can apply these step to create yours.

http://www.instructables.com/id/Make-A-Simple-Operating-System/?utm_source=base&utm_medium=related-instructables&utm_campaign=related_test